# Why is this snippet not giving a run time error as stated in the Java Tutorials documentation?

Tags: java

```
public class Box {
    private Object object;

    public void set(Object object) { this.object = object; }
    public Object get() { return object; }
}
```

With reference to this text from the official Java tutorials docs and the above snippet, I tried to reproduce the runtime error. What is wrong with my code since it is not producing any runtime error?

> Since its methods accept or return an Object, you are free to pass in whatever you want, provided that it is not one of the primitive types. There is no way to verify, at compile time, how the class is used. One part of the code may place an Integer in the box and expect to get Integers out of it, while another part of the code may mistakenly pass in a String, resulting in a runtime error.

The code that I wrote.

```
public class Box {
    private Object obj;

    public void set(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    public Object get() {
        return obj;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Box g = new Box();
        System.out.println(g.get());
        g.set("hello again");
        System.out.println(g.get());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Box g = new Box();

    g.set("hello again");
    Integer i = (Integer) g.get();

    System.out.println(i + 1);
}
```

This code passes in a `String`, but attempts to retrieve an `Integer`. The compiler can't detect that this will fail. At runtime it throws a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding the example. It is not saying that passing in a `String` will result in an error. It is saying that passing in an `String` will result in an error when another part of the program is expecting to get an `Integer`.

For example:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Box g = new Box();
    g.set("hello again");
    Integer error = (Integer) g.get();
}
```

will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

It wont produce any run time error because, Every String is an Object.

It gives you the error when you try to Assign the object retrieved by get to some other Object of different type.

for ex:

```
 g.set("hello again");
 Integer i = (Integer) g.get(); // getting string and trying to cast it to integer.
```